# Link to show_path to each record after searching among multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I use sunspot to search among multiple models.

After searching, the result is stored in `@query_results.each_hit_with_result`

But the question is how could I make a href link to  each search result's show_path

And if I show the search result in a table with two column

1st column is `id`
2nd column is the `field containing the search information`

How to do it ?

If the  result is from Model A it should show the  `comment field` for displaying

If the  result is from Model B it should show the  `article field` for displaying

### Model A

```
  searchable do
    text :comment
  end
```

### Model B

```
  searchable do
    text :article
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_a?(Model)` to check which model is the result related to.
For example, if your result is related with `Comment` then you would like to render `Comment partial` and if it is `Article` you would like to render `Comment partial`, then below code can help for this.

```
<% @query_results.each do |res| %>
  <% if res.is_a?(Comment) %>
    <%= render 'comment', comment: res %>
  <% if res.is_a?(Article) %>
    <%= render 'article', article: res %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now, you can access `comment` and `article` variables in your`comment` and `article` partials and display result as you like.